# Как применять условия if/else в SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Есть выборка в переменной.

Подскажите, как применять условия `if/else` в `sql`.
К примеру, если  `advert.hide='show'` , то ..... иначе другое.

```
$db_query="select *
    from ".DB_PREF."advert advert"
    ." where "
    ." advert.hide='show'  "
    ." and advert.end_putdate > ".$GLOBALS["timeGlobal"]." "
    ." order by premium_adv DESC, sort_time DESC limit ".KOL_NEW_ADVERT_TO_GLAV;
```

Comment: А где в запросе и что хотите этим сделать конкретно? А то так можно спокойно вас в документацию отправить)) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `IF`:

```
 select IF (advert.hide='show', 'Опубликовано', 'Скрыто') from ...
```

Функция выглядит во общем виде, так:

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

Если `expr1` истина тогда `IF()` возвращает `expr2`, в противном случае возвращает `expr3`.

Comment: Только следует помнить, что не все диалекты SQL поддерживают такую функцию. Однако, если речь об MySQL, то это довольно компактный вариант по сравнению с CASE.

Comment: Да, хорошо подмечено. Если использовать из популярных баз данных, например MSSQL, PostgreSql, Oracle, то данная фунция не работает, но в данном случае скорее всего идет вопрос про MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой задачи лучше всего воспользоваться выражением `CASE`, ему можно передать требуемое условие `hide='show'` и в зависимости от того, принимает оно `TRUE` или `FALSE` вернуть нужно значение. Один из возможных вариантов использования `CASE` приводится ниже

```
$db_query="select
   id,
   hide,
   end_putdate,
   premium_adv,
   sort_time,
   CASE WHEN hide='show' THEN 'Опубликовано' ELSE 'Не опубликовано' END AS hide
from ".DB_PREF."advert advert"
." where "
." advert.hide='show'  "
." and advert.end_putdate > ".$GLOBALS["timeGlobal"]." "
." order by premium_adv DESC, sort_time DESC limit ".KOL_NEW_ADVERT_TO_GLAV;
```